# git svn fetch - How to always ignore old revisions

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I checked out a big SVN into a git and saved time by ignoring old revisions.

```
git svn fetch -r 220350:HEAD
```

Unfortunately if I want to update the git and get newer revisions after they where cmomited to the SVN and I simply use "fetch", git svn starts fetching the older revisions starting at 1 again.

**Question:**

How can I tell git svn to always ignore revisions earlier than 220350?
I would like to simply enter

```
git svn fetch
```

and get the newest updates that where added after my last fetch.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do this.